# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::citas()

Tags: eloquent, orm, laravel-8

I need to obtain the appointments of a patient who is in the clinics that have a doctor.
A doctor may have several clinics associated with him.

I have a 1:n relationship between appointments and clinics. 1 appointment occurs at 1 clinic and 1 clinic has many appointments.
My Models:

```
class Cita extends Model
{
    public function clinica()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Clinica');
    }
}

class Clinica extends Model
{
    public function citas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Cita')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

And in my controller I have:

```
public function indexpaciente($paciente_id)
{
    $paciente = Paciente::find($paciente_id); 
    
    $clinicas = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->clinicas()->where('estado', '=', 1);   // clinicas del doctor
    
    $citas = $clinicas->citas()->where('paciente_id', '=', $paciente_id)->get(); // citas asociadas a las clinicas del doctor
    
    dd($citas);
```

The citas table is as follows:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('citas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        
        $table->string('title')->nullable;
        $table->string('descripcion')->nullable;
        
        $table->dateTime("start")->nullable();
        $table->dateTime("end")->nullable();
        
        $table->unsignedBiginteger('paciente_id')->nullable(); // paciente
        $table->foreign('paciente_id')->references('id')->on('pacientes')->onDelete('cascade');
        
        $table->unsignedBiginteger('profesional_id')->nullable(); // doctor que lo atendió
        $table->foreign('profesional_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        
        $table->unsignedBiginteger('clinica_id')->nullable(); // clinica
        $table->foreign('clinica_id')->references('id')->on('clinicas')->onDelete('cascade');
        
        $table->unsignedBiginteger('creadapor_id')->nullable(); // quien la creó
        $table->foreign('creadapor_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        
        $table->integer('roldelquelacreo')->default(1); //  rol a quien pertenece para calculo de comisiones
        
        $table->string('encabezado')->nullable(); // encabezado de la epicrisis
        $table->string('glosa','500')->nullable(); // solo para los proefesionales
        $table->unsignedDecimal('total', $precision = 11, $scale = 2)->nullable(); //suma de las prestaciones con 2 decimales max: $99.999.999,99
        
        
        $table->integer('estado')->default(1); //  1= cita creada  0= cita bloqueada
        
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I have both models defined as appropriate in a 1:n relationship but it still tells me that appointments are undefined.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... this is an English only site, can you translate your question?

Comment: I have just done it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `hasMany` doesn't have a `withTimestamps` method .... that is on `belongsToMany` .... where have you defined a Belongs to Many relationship (as the error says there is one some where) ... the error does not match your code

Comment: I removed `withTimestamps` from the model and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`where` does not return a result, it is a builder method. You are using what is returned from `where` as a result (Model in this case) when it is still the builder that is building the query. You would have to execute the query to get a result. Even if you get the result, it seems like you want to get many results, you would get a Collection back from `get`, which wouldn't have a relationship method `citas`. So there are multiple problems here.

This would get you many "clinicas":

```
$clinicas = Auth::user()->clinicas()->where('estado', '=', 1)->get();
```

Which would be a Collection of Models, so not sure what particular Model you would want to be calling the relationship method on.

This would get you 1 'clinica':

```
$clinica = Auth::user()->clinicas()->where('estado', '=', 1)->firstOrFail();
```

Then you could call the relationship method on this result:

```
$clinica->citas()->....;
```

Your error message does not match the code you have provided as you have not defined a Belongs To Many relationship here.

Comment: I removed `withTimestamps` from the model and it worked. Thank you.